# Favicon not reflecting on iPhone/iOS mobile devices

Tags: html, ios, angular, iphone, favicon

I have a configurable favicon which gets change dynamically.
It is working fine on chrome, android, desktop. but favicon not showing on iPhone. it is taking some old favicon which was earlier loaded with website.

I have tried even with placing my hardcoded path of favicon, but in iPhone it still takes old one which is not present in code anywhere.

````
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="16x16" href="favicon.ico?v=2" id="favicon-for-ios">
  <!-- favicon png files -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="favicon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favicon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favicon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favicon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favicon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favicon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favicon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favicon.png?v=2">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png?v=2" type="image/png">


  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon.png?v=2">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png?v=2">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png?v=2">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=3">
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=2" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">```
````

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache?

Comment: Yes. tried with cache clear. tried with other iphone devices aswell